# Should the 's' be capitalized in Scholar I.D

Tags: capitalization

Should the 's' be capitalized in Scholar I.D.

The sentence reads as: **The Professor needs to see your scholar I.D. before you proceed.**

Comment: Given that you've capitalised ***Professor*** (which most of us *wouldn't* do today), I think that *for you in particular* capitalising all elements of ***Scholar ID*** would be appropriate. Note that most people wouldn't include periods in ***I.D.*** either, but that's a whole nother ball game.

Comment: There is no way to know. That institution has written it like that. There is no rule for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

By *Scholar I.D.*, I assume you are referring to [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), Google's [search engine for scholarly works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Scholar).  If this is the case, your *Scholar ID* is not just another name for a student ID but the name of an actual, specific service.  Therefore, as a proper noun, it should indeed be capitalized: ***Scholar ID***.

In contrast, if it were simply another name for a generic *student ID* then it would not be, just as *student ID* is not capitalized.